# Can I reference another property in messages.properties? if yes, How?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, properties-file

I trying to using referencing a property to another property in messages.properties.
when searching for answers in the internet mostly answered like this:

```
referenced.text.property=Some text
new.text.property=${referenced.text.property}
```

but it outputs only "${referenced.text.property}" without quotes in thymeleaf.
this code only works on application.properties

Comment: A property file is simply a list of key-value pairs with no interpolation. You can use a templating engine like Thymeleaf or Maven plugin to preprocess it.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar how do you preprocess it? I tried doing it with Thymeleaf th:text="#{new.text.property}" but it just output ${referenced.text.property}

Comment: You cannot. You can use parameters but those are with an index and you would need to pass in the values in the correct order. Without (re)writing parts of the `MessageSource` you are using this isn't possible out-of-the-box. There is a work-around mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22145821/internal-references-in-propertyfiles-for-spring-messagesource). The problem is that you might end-up with properties from a different language in another one (so if you default is EN and you have a dedicated one for DE, they might influence each other).

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks. but it looks like i'm gonna stick to just copy pasting values until maybe in the future the devs of springboot can allow this out-of-the-box

Answer (score -2):

Order is important!

You need have `referenced.text.property` **before** `new.text.property`

Sample: https://github.com/NoraUi/NoraUi/blob/master/src/test/resources/UnitTest4CLI.properties

in java you can code this order:

```
protected static Properties initPropertiesFile(ClassLoader loader, String propertiesFileName) {
    if (loader != null) {
        final InputStream in = loader.getResourceAsStream(propertiesFileName);
        final Properties props = new Properties();
        try {
            if (in == null) {
                log.error(Messages.getMessage(CONTEXT_PROPERTIES_FILE_NOT_FOUND), propertiesFileName);
            } else {
                log.info("Reading properties file ({}).", propertiesFileName);
                props.load(in);
            }
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            log.error("error Context.initPropertiesFile()", e);
        }
        log.info("Loaded properties from {} = {}.", propertiesFileName, props);
        return props;
    }
    return null;
}
```

**Springboot:**

```
--spring.config.location=your/path/application.yml
```

**Maven:**

```
<filters>                    
    <filter>src/main/resources/messages.properties</filter>
</filters>
```

Comment: did not work in messages.property but  works on application.property

Comment: *.property or *.properties? Have you more information please (springboot, maven, ...)? Or better a sample on github?

Comment: sorry for wrong the wrong spelling, it is .properties in the project and uses springboot as framework and the template is thymeleaf. but still does not work in messages.properties

Comment: you find solution with add Maven filter in good order?